# How do I customize a UITableViewCell to incorporate multiple sized images in a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

[image]

I am loading multiple (3-4) items from a JSON feed (the number will vary depending on the day).  Each item will have 4 attributes: icon, title, subtitle, and large_image.  After parsing and displaying the first item, I would like the next item to be displayed.

My question is: can I customize a UITableViewCell to look like this for each item in the feed?  If so, how do I do this?  Through google/stackoverflow searches, I've seen how to do the icon image + title + subtitle in a custom cell, but nothing about how to incorporate the large image as well.

If not a custom UITableView, how do I enable this?  Do I make individual UILabels and UIImageViews that dynamically render based on the number of items in the feed?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you want both a small icon *and* the large image in every cell in your table view?

Comment: Just make a custom cell with whatever subviews you want.

Comment: I'm just beginning with iOS dev...can you point to a good tutorial that can get me on my way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any. But it's not difficult. In IB just make sure the cell type is set to custom, size it how you want and drag in whatever you want. Create a custom UITableViewCell class and add outlets for all your subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple but good for beginners in iOS.

Here are the steps:

```
Create a xib file (which should be a subclass of UITableViewCell. Drag and drop 2 UILabels, and place it how you want for each row. Drag and drop 2 imageviews as well. One should be for icon, (preferably smaller in size) and other one should depict the large image. 

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath method of tableview, try to load the custom cell object and pass the values you have in json parsed array (formatted array containing data for each row). Update your cell UI in cellforRowAtIndexPath.`
```

[Click here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) - `this is something which best fits your issue, you can customize more according to your need. (add label, largeimageview)`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a custom uitableviewcell. And the question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014105/where-is-a-good-tutorial-for-making-a-custom-uitableviewcell) and there is a tutorial link too. Start with a simple example.